# Declare cursor is not executing

Tags: rpgle

I have converted one RPGLE program to SQLRPGLE, i did that many times. strange issues i am facing this time.
(1) SQLCODE setting up to 077952576 as soon as program executing, not sure why.
(2) when i am running in debug Declare cursor statement is not getting executed, nut other following sql statement getting hit.

```
  Exec Sql                                                   
     DECLARE My_cursor CURSOR for                           
     select * FROM File1    where FLAG <> 'Y' 
     Order by Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5;
```

Please advise, Thanks

Comment: I am not able to edit question, Actually the only issue is of SQLCODE, why does it setting up to some value when program start run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DECLARE CURSOR` is not an executable statement.  It's a compile time statement.

You shouldn't be checking SQLCODE/SQLSTATE after it...

Take a look at this program...

```
**FREE
ctl-opt main(mymain);
ctl-opt option(*srcstmt);
ctl-opt datfmt(*ISO) timfmt(*ISO);
ctl-opt cvtopt(*NODATETIME);

dcl-proc MyMain;
  dcl-s company char(3);
  dcl-s part    char(25);
  dcl-s desc    char(30);
  dcl-s msg     char(50);
  dcl-s selComp char(3);
  dcl-s myTimestamp timestamp;

  exec sql
    set option
       datfmt=*ISO, timfmt=*ISO;

  selComp = 'A06';
  exsr OpenCursor;
  exsr FetchData;
  exec SQL close C1;

  selComp = 'A15';
  exsr OpenCursor;
  exsr FetchData;
  exec SQL close C1;

  *INLR = *ON;
  return;

  begsr DeclareCursor;
     exec SQL
       declare C1 cursor for
          select pmco#, pmpart, pmdesc
           from pdpmast
           where pmco# = :selComp;
  endsr;

  begsr OpenCursor;
    exec SQL open C1;
  endsr;

  begsr FetchData;
    exec sql fetch next from C1 into :company, :part, :desc;
    msg = company + ':' + part + ':' + desc;
    dsply msg;
  endsr;
end-proc;
```

Note that this is a working (example) program.   But the DeclareCursor subroutine is never actually called!  It doesn't need to be, even though a host variable is used in the `WHERE` clause.

The value of the host variable is use when the `OPEN` is executed.

Also note that in embedded SQL as shown above, `SET OPTION` is a compile time statement.  In fact, there can only be a single `SET OPTION` statement in the entire source member and it must be the first SQL statement that the pre-compiler sees.

Comment: Just a note, `SET OPTION` is only executable in a `REXX` program, otherwise it is not executable and must precede all other SQL statements.

Comment: SQL Reference says SET option isn't valid in REXX? [Actions allowed on SQL Statements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzactallow.htm)